# FileStream or WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, filestream, ms-wopi

I'm currently generating some preview with the `Wopi` and the `Office Web App` technologies from Microsoft, and i'm having an issue. Sorry for my bad english, but i'll try to express myself as well as possible.

So ! I'm generating the preview by downloading a file's content and storing it into an `HttpContent`.
First, i tried this on files that were in the `~/App_Data/` of my project. I read it's content with the `FileStream` class and transformed it into `HttpContent` byusing this : `StreamContent(myFileStream)`. So, THIS is working perfectly !

BUT, i need my project to deal with files that are stored on servers only reachable from the internet (So physical urls should look like this : `http://myServer/res/file.pdf` for example). I couldn't use the `FileStream` class here, so i did it like this :

```
byte[] tmp;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    tmp = client.DownloadData("http://myServer/res/file.pdf");
}
myHttpContent = new ByteArrayContent(tmp);
```

The thing is that this little sample seems to be working, but the preview isn't generated after that, and it is the only piece of code that i changed. I checked some stuff befor posting here, so : i do have access to the file and i am allowed to read it.

So, my question is, it this a good way to get the files content, is it outdated, what should i do to try to patch this ?

I hope my post is clear enough and thanks for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do the following

```
MemoryStream ms;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://myServer/res/file.pdf"));
}
```

Then use the memory stream should behave identically to your filestream.